# Run Azure databricks notebook(python) via Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, databricks, azure-databricks, terraform-provider-databricks

Please help me with terraform script to run Azure databricks notebook(python)in other environment.Thank you

Comment: Do you have a specific issue? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Actually i need to run Azure_Databricks notebook using terraform template hence not able to find any module /argument for same in terraform .Please confirm if any guidance .
To launch databricks using terraform i have followed below link.
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/databricks_workspace.html

Comment: You can use https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databrickslabs/databricks/latest/docs/resources/job#notebook_task-configuration-block to schedule notebook via Azure Databricks Jobs scheduler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the supported developer tools help you develop Azure Databricks applications using the **Databricks REST API**, **Databricks Utilities**, **Databricks CLI**, and tools outside the Azure Databricks environment.

**Reference:** [Azure Databricks - Developer Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should synchronise Databricks Notebooks via [databricks_notebook](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databrickslabs/databricks/latest/docs/resources/notebook) and scheduling every *quartz_cron_expression* through [databricks_job](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databrickslabs/databricks/latest/docs/resources/job#notebook_task-configuration-block) *notebook_task*. See example configuration [here](https://github.com/databrickslabs/terraform-provider-databricks/blob/master/scripts/azvnet-integration/databricks.tf#L204).